# Android: strange weight inversion in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

This is the xml layout i'm working on:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:id="@+id/scrollConfirm" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  </ScrollView>

  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_marginTop="20px"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:id="@+id/imageNumpad" 
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/myicon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Since I have setted the ScrollView with `layout_weight="2"` and the LinearLayout (child) with `layout_weight="1"` I expected that the ScrollView will use up twice free space that the LinearLayout. But I obtain the opposite result. The ScrollView is smaller than LinearLayout. 
Whereas if I set for the ScrollView `layout_weight="1"` and LinearLayout with `layout_weight="2"`, the ScrollView is greater  than LinearLayou.

How is this possible??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Weight get inverse because you are using `match_parent` as the `layout_height`. The weight is used to distribute the remaining empty space or take away space when the total sum is larger than the `LinearLayout`. Set your heights to **0dip** it will work.

i.e., 
set `layout_height = "0dip"` for both `ScrollView` and inner `LinearLayout`.

**Reference :**

[The use of layout_weight with Android layouts](http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/)